# Accessing "file" structure from user space

Tags: c

In reference to linux kernel, I would like to access the "file" structure information like current file offset in a user space C program. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a FILE* to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "in reference to linux kernel" relevant, or misleading information? That is, are you asking about the kernel-level open file description and its status, or the C library-level `FILE *` used in stdio? Either way, you cannot poke at the internals yourself. There are accessor functions you can use: `ftello(f)` for stdio, or `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` for file descriptors.

Comment: @R..I am asking about the kernel-level open file descriptor

Comment: Hmm, there may be a way via /proc too... Yep. Look in `/proc/$pid/fdinfo/$fd`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access kernel structures in userspace.